# Vim pumvisible() call putting in random text

Tags: vim

I'm using the spf13 package for Vim. However, whenever I enter some text and press escape, some weird characters get appended to it.

For example, if I type this and press escape,

```
hello
```

I get this:

```
hellopumvisible() ? "\" : "\
```

There is a mapping on my .vimrc file that reads like this, which I think might be responsible:

```
" some convenient mappings
inoremap <expr> <Esc>      pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>" : "\<Esc>"
inoremap <expr> <CR>       pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
inoremap <expr> <Down>     pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Down>"
inoremap <expr> <Up>       pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<Up>"
inoremap <expr> <C-d>      pumvisible() ? "\<PageDown>\<C-p>\<C-n>" : "\<C-d>"
inoremap <expr> <C-u>      pumvisible() ? "\<PageUp>\<C-p>\<C-n>" : "\<C-u>"
```

I guess it's taken from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improve_completion_popup_menu. But for some reason, this is giving me odd behavior. Any advice?

**EDIT:**
Here's the output of `:inoremap <esc>`

`i  <Esc>       *@pumvisible() ? '<C-E>' : '<C-R>=<SNR>32_FlushBuffer()<CR>pumvisible() ? "\<C-E>" : "\<Esc>"'`

`i  <Esc>       * pumvisible() ? "\<C-E>" : "\<Esc>"`

And I'm using Vim 7.3 on Windows 8.

### Solution

The autoclose plugin is interfering with  mapping. I've written the steps to remove it here: http://crossplatform.net/dev/vim-spf13-writes-random-characters-when-pressing-escape.html. It works fine now.

Comment: What's your Vim `:version` & OS? Have you done `:BundleInstall` to install the plugins in the package yet? Have you installed any additional plugins or made additional changes?

Comment: What message display if `:inoremap <esc>` ?

Comment: @mattn: I've added the output of :inoremap <esc>. The bundle installation was done by the batch script that came with spf13. It installed the .vim.bundles file and it took a while. I did not install anything else after that.

Comment: It seems that you has some thing affective plugin already. And probably, it has function `s:FlushBuffer`. Check with `:verbose inoremap <ESC>`.

Comment: @mattn You're spot on. It was the autoclose plugin. I removed it, and things are back to normal.

Answer (score 14):

Probably, this maybe FAQ. And this will be helpful for others. So I copied answer from comment line above.

## When you have a problem about vim mappings.

Check `:verbose inoremap` at the first.

If you know the keys which have problem, then do it with specified key, for example `:verbose inoremap <esc>`.

Answer (score 9):

This fixes it for me,
in your ~/.vimrc or ~/.config/nvim/init.vim file add:

```
let g:AutoClosePreserveDotReg = 0
```

Comment: This was it for me! Could you add some more info about why this is the issue?